# Check if a facebook app does exist using its id

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a **service** that **requires** the user to provide it with a *Facebook's app id*, right now the user can type in anything and it will accept it, i am trying to enforce some rules

> by calling the graph and checking if that app exists in the first place.

but i don't know how to get that done right now.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Would you be able to provide more information in your question? Try to be as specific as possible and include what you've tried. At the moment it's difficult to tell what is is that you're after. We don't know your circumstances or what you're trying to do. Please read [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you for your kind words,, actually I was trying to do something pretty easy but i didn't know how to do it properly,, i answered the question please refer to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

### It turned out to be pretty easy I just didn't know how to do it properly at the time.

First of all the context in which I am going to answer is through an asp.net MVC 5 project.

In order to keep things clean we are going to build a little helper class called AppData .

---

> ```
>  using System.Web.Helpers;
>  using System.Net;
>  public class AppData
>  {
>     public string id { get; set; }
>     public string name { get; set; }
>     public string description { get; set; }
>     public string category { get; set; }
>     public string link { get; set; }
>     public string icon_url { get; set; }
>     public string logo_url { get; set; }
>     public string company { get; set; }
>     public int daily_active_users { get; set; }
>     public int monthly_active_users { get; set; }
>     public int daily_active_users_rank { get; set; }
>     public int monthly_active_users_rank { get; set; }
>     public static AppData GetAppData(string id)
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             string url = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + id;
>             var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
>             return Json.Decode<AppData>(json);
>         }
>         catch 
>         {
>             return null;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

this class will have the responsibility of calling the Facebook graph using the Facebook app id and then deserializing ( decoding ) the json response if any to a new instance of the AppData Class and returning it back to the user,, if there is no such app we will return null to the user,, the user can then check against null value to know if that app id is real or not and get useful info for their request over the network.